# Optimized way to find Padovan numbers

Tags: c#, algorithm, optimization

What is the most optimized way to find [Padovan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padovan_sequence)?
This is what I have currently.
Even though it returns correct result, I want to know what is the quickest method possible.

```
        long Sum = 0;
        public long Get(int number)
        {
            Sum = 0;      
            if (number == 0 || number == 1 || number == 2)
                return 1;
            return GetPadovanAlt(number);
        }

        public long GetPadovanAlt(int n)
        {
          if(n == 0 || n == 1 || n == 2)
          return 1;
          return GetPadovanAlt(n - 2) + GetPadovanAlt(n - 3);

        }
```

Comment: Why has this "for loop" approach been deleted? Was it incorrect?

Comment: (LukStorms has undeleted his ["For Loop-answer"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40116153/3789665). Still searching an approach to compute _P(n)_ from _P(n/k±o)_ for small _k_ and _o_. Using _P(n) = P(n-2)+P(n-4)+P(n-8)_ or _2P(n-4)+3P(n-8)+P(n-12)_ results in the evaluation of the same number of two-operand arithmetic operations, with the effect on loop control entirely similar to loop unrolling. While it appears to reduce "shifting the values", that can be eliminated by unrolling & renaming, whether explicit or implicit.

Comment: @MareInfinitus  Sometimes it happens that who's writing the answer find something wrong or unideal with his post. And to avoid pesky downvotes it's then safer to delete it, look for the right answer, then edit and undelete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you specifically ask about C# and optimization I have provided code which I think will set you in the correct direction.  First the output of the program:

```
From https://oeis.org/A000931
Ref: 1  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  2  2  3  4  5  7  9  12  16  21  28  37  49  65  86  114  151  200  265
Rec: 1  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  2  2  3  4  5  7  9  12  16  21  28  37  49  65  86  114  151  200  265
Qik: 1  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  2  2  3  4  5  7  9  12  16  21  28  37  49  65  86  114  151  200  265

Recursive method:   709.238100 ms   checksum: 35676949
Quick     method:     0.004800 ms   checksum: 35676949
```

As you can see there is a considerable difference between the recursive and the 'quick' method.  There are several reasons for this.  First is that recursion requires considerable extra work moving addresses & values on and off the stack for each function call (and there are a lot of calls).  Second this code uses a statically allocated array (not thread safe) as a work area when calling the quick method.  You could allocate the array inside the method but that would require a small amount of extra time.

The quick method does little more than enter a for loop to calculate the values directly into the static array.  You could make a class of this and initialize the first four array values only once.  You could also keep track of the last value calculated so that you could start from that position when calculating larger values, or use the 'n' as an index to directly retrieve a pre-calculated value.

Here is the code (creatively named ConsoleApplication1 ;-))

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Program {
        static public long GetPadovanRecursive(int n) {
            if (n == 0) { return 1; }
            if (n == 1) { return 0; }
            if (n == 2) { return 0; }
            if (n == 3) { return 1; }
            return GetPadovanRecursive(n - 2) + GetPadovanRecursive(n - 3);
            }

        static int N_Max = 8192;
        static long[] pdvn = new long[N_Max];

        static public long GetPadovanQuick(int n) {
            Debug.Assert(n < N_Max);
            if (n == 0) { return 1; }
            if (n == 1) { return 0; }
            if (n == 2) { return 0; }
            if (n == 3) { return 1; }

            pdvn[3] = 1;
            for (int i = 4; i <= n; i++) {
                pdvn[i] = pdvn[i - 2] + pdvn[i - 3];
                }
            return pdvn[n];
            }


        static void Main(string[] args) {
            const int Count = 64;
            Stopwatch stp = new Stopwatch();

            // Sanity check
            Console.WriteLine("From https://oeis.org/A000931");
            Console.WriteLine("Ref: 1  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  2  2  3  4  5  7  9  12  16  21  28  37  49  65  86  114  151  200  265");
            Console.Write("Rec: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
                Console.Write("{0}  ", GetPadovanRecursive(i));
                }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write("Qik: ");
            for (var i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
                Console.Write("{0}  ", GetPadovanQuick(i));
                }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

            long sum = 0;
            stp.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++) {
                sum += GetPadovanRecursive(i);
                }
            stp.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Recursive method: {0,12:F6} ms   checksum: {1}", stp.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds, sum);


        sum = 0;
        stp.Restart();
        for (var i = 0; i < Count; i++) {
            sum += GetPadovanQuick(i);
            }
        Console.WriteLine("Quick     method: {0,12:F6} ms   checksum: {1}", stp.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds, sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice approach to warm-up & sanity check.

Comment: Thanks, it comes from a long life of making mistakes ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The Ol' For Loop might not be as fancy as recursion.
But if it does the job, then there's no reason to look down on it.

```cs
public static BigInteger GetPadovan(int n)
{
    if (n > 156 || n < -316) return GetBigPadovan(n);
    return GetSmallPadovan(n);
}

static BigInteger GetBigPadovan(int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    if (n == 1 || n == 2) return 1;

    BigInteger padovan = 0, prev1 = 1, prev2 = 1, prev3 = 1;
            
    if (n > 2)
    {
        for (var i = 2; i < n; i++)
        {
            padovan = prev2 + prev3;
            prev3 = prev2;
            prev2 = prev1;
            prev1 = padovan;
        }
    }
    else if (n < 0)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i > n; i--)
        {
            padovan = prev3 - prev1;
            prev3 = prev2;
            prev2 = prev1;
            prev1 = padovan;
        }
    }

    return padovan;
}

static long GetSmallPadovan(int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    if (n == 1 || n == 2) return 1;
    if (n > 156 || n < -316) return 0;

    long padovan = 0, prev1 = 1, prev2 = 1, prev3 = 1;

    if (n > 2)
    {
        for (var i = 2; i < n; i++)
        {
            padovan = prev2 + prev3;
            prev3 = prev2;
            prev2 = prev1;
            prev1 = padovan;
        }
    }
    else if (n < 0)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i > n; i--)
        {
            padovan = prev3 - prev1;
            prev3 = prev2;
            prev2 = prev1;
            prev1 = padovan;
        }
    }

    return padovan;
}
```

The code will also calculate for the negative numbers.
And it can handle P(N) with N above 156.
(Since [Int64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) is to small for the bigger padovans)

**Testing:**

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 21; i++) Console.Write("{0} ", GetPadovan(i));
```

Rextest [here](https://rextester.com/GYW5154)

Returns:

```
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 12, 16, 21, 28, 37, 49, 65, 86, 114, 151, 200, 265,
```

***Other methods***

**New faster recursive:**

By using parameters it can be done without an explosion of forked function calls.
Using the long type, so P(N) for N between -316 to 156 only.

```
static public long GetPadovanRecursive(int n, long prev1 = 1, long prev2 = 1, long prev3 = 1)
{
    if (n > 156 || n < -316) return 0;
    if (n > 2) return GetPadovanRecursive(--n, prev2 + prev3, prev1, prev2);
    if (n < 0) return GetPadovanRecursive(++n, prev3 - prev1, prev1, prev2);
    return prev1;
}
```

**Old slow recursive:**

```
static public long GetPadovanSlowRecursive(int n)
{
    if (n == 0 || n == 1 || n == 2) return 1;
    if (n < 0 || n > 156) return 0;
    return GetPadovanSlowRecursive(n - 2) + GetPadovanSlowRecursive(n - 3);
}
```

**The Binomial method:**

[image: Padovan sequence]

```
public static BigInteger GetPadovanBinomial(int n)
{
    BigInteger result = 0;
    int k = n + 2;
              
    for (int m = k/3; m <= k/2; m++)
    {
        result += GetBinomialCoefficient(m,(k-m*2));
    }
    return result;
}

public static BigInteger GetBinomialCoefficient(int n, int k)
{
    BigInteger result = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
    {
        result *= n - (k - i);
        result /= i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

**The combinations method:**

This makes use of the peculiar fact that P(n) is the number of ways to write (n + 2) as a sum of 2 & 3.

```
static BigInteger GetPadovanSumCombos(int n)
{
    if (n < 0) return 0;
    int m = n + 2;
    int min3 = m % 2;
    int max2 = (min3 == 0) ? m / 2 : (m / 2) - 1;
    BigInteger result = 0;

    var factorials = new BigInteger[min3 + max2 + 1];
    factorials[1] = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= min3 + max2; i++) factorials[i] = i*factorials[i-1];

    for (int m2 = max2, m3 = min3; m2 >= 0; m2 -= 3, m3 += 2)
    {
        if (m2 == 0||m3 == 0) result += 1;
        else if (m3 == 2) result += (((m2+1) * (m2 + 2)) / 2);
        else result += factorials[m2 + m3] / (factorials[m3] * factorials[m2]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

**Comparing the speeds:**

```
var timer = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch(); timer.Stop();
var padovan = new BigInteger();
int num = 72;

timer.Restart(); padovan = GetPadovanSlowRecursive(num); timer.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("GetPadovanSlowRecursive({0}):\t{1}\t{2,12:F6} ms", num, padovan, timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

timer.Restart(); padovan = GetPadovanRecursive(num); timer.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("GetPadovanRecursive({0}):\t{1}\t{2,12:F6} ms", num, padovan, timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

timer.Restart(); padovan = GetPadovanBinomial(num); timer.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("GetPadovanBinomial({0}):\t\t{1}\t{2,12:F6} ms", num, padovan, timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

timer.Restart(); padovan = GetPadovanSumCombos(num); timer.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("GetPadovanSumCombos({0}):\t{1}\t{2,12:F6} ms", num, padovan, timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);

timer.Restart(); padovan = GetPadovan(num); timer.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("GetPadovan({0}):\t\t\t{1}\t{2,12:F6} ms", num, padovan, timer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
```

Returned:

```
GetPadovanSlowRecursive(72):    448227521       13283,251300 ms
GetPadovanRecursive(72):        448227521           0,278300 ms
GetPadovanBinomial(72):         448227521           0,486300 ms
GetPadovanSumCombos(72):        448227521           0,722400 ms
GetPadovan(72):                 448227521           0,365900 ms
```

Comment: In C, `=+ ` was a (deprecated) way to denote `+=` which meant _increment by_. If the `+` in `=+ ` _does_ have a meaning, I'm too scared to look it up - if it doesn't, please remove it.

Comment: Lol, surprised that actually didn't raise an error. In fact it made no difference at all. Removed it.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: (Good thing I don't know C#.) If you used `if (c) st else sf`, you might not need to initialise `var padovan` in `GetPadovan()`. Instead of huge literals, how about `var
        prev1 = new BigInteger(GetSmallPadovan(THRESHOLD)),
        prev2 = new BigInteger(GetSmallPadovan(THRESHOLD-1)),
        prev3 = new BigInteger(GetSmallPadovan(THRESHOLD-2))`?

Answer (score 2):

You are doing more work than you need by using recursion.  When you calculate `GetPadovan(42)` you fire off a binary tree of recursions, which will include sub-calls like `GetPadovan(12)`.  That `GetPadovan(12)` will be called many times on many branches of the recursion tree.  Put in something like `if (n == 12) then print("*");` to see how many.

When you calculate a specific Padovan number, store it and retrieve the stored number for second and subsequent calls.  Alternatively switch to a non-recursive calculation: start from Padovan(3) and work up, keeping track of four numbers: P(n), P(n-1), P(n-2) and P(n-3) as you proceed.

ETA: running a quick program, `GetPadovan(42)` calls `GetPadovan(12)` 1897 times.  Recursion is definitely not the fastest way to go.

Comment: A time/space tradeoff.

Comment: Only for storing all numbers.  The least space is to store four numbers, as in my last sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a member of the Fibonacci sequence can be computed rapidly raising a 2×2 matrix to the `n`th power (offsets vary between definitions) and taking the top-left element as the result, the same applies to the sequence of Padovan numbers:

```
F: 1 1   P: 0 0 1
   1 0      1 0 1
            0 1 0 (or its transpose)
```

Not fluent in *math*, code for those that can more easily think in, say, C#:

```
const long BIG_LIMIT = 1 << 30; // even 1L<<31 is too large
/** computes the <code>n</code>th Padovan number.<br/>
 * (index 0 for the first <code>1</code> in the run of three
 *  ("The triangle interpretation"))<br/>
 * This uses exponentiation of <code><br/>
 * 0 0 1 <br/>
 * 1 0 1 <br/>
 * 0 1 0 </code>by <code>n+5</code>
 * (returning the top-left element) */
static BigInteger padovan(long n) {
    if (n < 3)
        return (n < 0) ? 0 : 1;
// add offset from "non-negative" to "triangle" definition
    n += 5;
    long b, bit = highestOneBit(n),
        a = b = 0, c = 1; // consecutive Padovan numbers

    BigInteger p1 = a, p2 = b, p3 = c;
// raise to the nth power by squaring&multiplying
    while (0 < BIG_LIMIT) { // <= 0: use BigInteger from start
        long bc,
            A  = a*a + 2*(bc= b*c),
            B  = b*(2*a+b) + c*c;
        if (1 == (bit >>= 1))
            return 0 == (n&1) ? A : B; 
        long C  = 2*(a*c + bc) + b*b;
        //  D  = a²+2ab+b²+2bc+c² = (a+b+c)² - 2ac
        if (BIG_LIMIT < B) {
            if (0 == (n&bit)) {
                p3 = C;
                p2 = B;
                p1 = A;
            } else {
                p3 = A + B;
                p2 = C;
                p1 = B;
            }
            break;
        }
        if (0 == (n&bit)) {
            c = C;
            b = B;
            a = A;
        } else {
            c = A + B;
            b = C;
            a = B;
        }
    }

// raise to the nth power by squaring&multiplying
    while (true) {
        if (1 == (bit >>= 1))
            return 0 == (n&1)
                ? p1*p1 + 2 * p2*p3
                : p2*(2*p1+p2) + p3*p3;
        BigInteger
            p23= p2*p3,                // common to A & C
            s2 = p2*p2,                // common to B & C
            A  = p1*p1 + 2 * p23,
            B  = 2*p1*p2 + s2 + p3*p3,
            C  = 2*(p1*p3 + p23) + s2;
        if (0 == (n&bit)) {
            p3 = C;
            p2 = B;
            p1 = A;
        } else {
            p3 = A + B; // D = A + B
            p2 = C;
            p1 = B;
        }
    // ok, so the matrix squaring is multiplied out.
    // and common subexpressions are "eliminated"
    //  at the source code level.
    // and "the single step" uses explicit renaming
    //  and one addition.
    // So what - "most optimized" was called for,
    //  premature or not
    }
}
/** @return the most significant bit set - zero, if none. */
static long highestOneBit(long i) {
// Hacker'sDelight, Figure 3-1
    i |= (i >>  1);
    i |= (i >>  2);
    i |= (i >>  4);
    i |= (i >>  8);
    i |= (i >> 16);
    i |= (i >> 32);
    return i - (i >> 1);
}
```

Conversion to `BigInteger` left above as an experiment… (the expressions have been chosen with (Java's) BigInteger implementation in mind)(For arguments in the two digit range, an "addition loop" was faster in my experiments. Too lazy to figure out how to take advantage of that.)

Comment: I tried this in C#, but the java `Integer.highestOneBit` is not in C#. But after replaceing that by `(int)Math.Pow(2, Convert.ToString(n, 2).Length - 1)` it worked in C#. And it's speed was comparable with my GetSmallPadovan.

Comment: `it's speed was comparable with my GetSmallPadovan` Try with 6+ digit arguments.

Comment: Indeed, you are right.  I hadn't tested for n > 156 because with that long type it would generate negative numbers. But with using BigInteger, your method will run increasingly faster for n > 3000. [Here](http://rextester.com/AZOS20512) is a test on rextester.

Comment: (Using a non-transcendental highestOneBit and allowing for a perfunctory warm-up, the crossover is _much_ lower. (Didn't fork: can you see/use the changes?))

Answer (score 0):

Can be done by calling only one method

```
public long GetPadovanAlt(int n)
    {
      if(n == 0 || n == 1 || n == 2)
      return 1;
      return GetPadovanAlt(n - 2) + GetPadovanAlt(n - 3);

    }
```

Comment: This approach only uses one method, but has exactly the same complexity issues as the original.  There is virtually no improvement over the original method here.

Answer (score 0):

The approach applied above is Recursive programming. It works well but ends up taking a lot of time for larger values of the number.

An iterative approach works much faster.

Here is a java program to demonstrate...

```
class PadovanNumber {

public static long findPadovanNumRec (int n) {
    if ((n == 0) || (n == 1) || (n == 2))
        return 1;
    return findPadovanNumRec(n - 2) + findPadovanNumRec(n - 3); 
}

public static void main (String args[]) {
    int num = (Integer.valueOf(args[0])).intValue();
    //long timeRecStart = System.currentTimeMillis();   
    //long answerRec = findPadovanNumRec(num);
    //long timeRecEnd = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    //System.out.println("Padovan Number Rec " + args[0] + " = " + answerRec + " Time Taken = " + (timeRecEnd - timeRecStart));
    long timeIterStart = System.currentTimeMillis();    
    long answerIter = findPadovanNumIter(num);
    long timeIterEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();  
    System.out.println("Padovan Number Iter " + args[0] + " = " + answerIter + " Time Taken = " + (timeIterEnd - timeIterStart));
}

public static long findPadovanNumIter (int n) {
    long sum = 0;
    long sumn1 = 1;
    long sumn2 = 1;
    long sumn3 = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        if ((i == 0) || (i == 1) || (i == 2))
            sum = 1;
        else {
            sum = sumn2 + sumn3;
            sumn3 = sumn2;
            sumn2 = sumn1;
            sumn1 = sum;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

}

Hope this helps. :-)

Comment: (The recursive approach is about(/"asymptotically") as fast using memoisation, see [rossum's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40114228/3789665), too.)

Comment: Yes. "Memoisation" will help as well. However, it will end up consuming O(n) memory as opposed to O(1) - constant memory used up in iterative approach...Wouldn't it?